# how to disable addressbar without using windows.open in javascript or jquery or other way

Tags: javascript, location

Hi I want to disable address bar as I don't want that user can edit anything in to the URL or modify the url. 
So basically I'm emailing link to them and by clicking they can complete require task and that'why I want to stop them to make any changes.

thanks

Comment: This is not possible. Think about the usability/security concerns with this and you will quickly see why. Giving the ability to hide the bar would likely mean you could edit it and thus re-style it, which could allow you to trick a user into thinking somewhere they aren't. The address bar is the central way for a user to determine where in the web they are.

Comment: yeah that's true. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are describing (give someone a link to do something, and only that thing) is typically solved with server-side validation rather than just hiding the URL. Often, you want to make use of a "nonce", that is a one-time secret value for each allowed action that users could not guess.

So for example http://www.example.com/validate-email/?nonce=d389mxfh47c

A user could not simply change the nonce to get a desired effect. The server can look up what the correct, authorized action is for that nonce when the user accesses/submits the page.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, yeah something like that could use; even can attach random id and cross check...
but didn't want to use but anyways ..thanks